# What is a good way to prevent cordova from prompting for phone info

Tags: cordova, prompt

I'm testing my phonegap code with the latest ripple emulator.  I keep getting prompts.  I know that this is because cordova 2.8.0 is unable to find a way to interface with the java on my phone.  I'm testing with my desktop machine and the browser emulator.  I don't get these messages on my phone when I pull my code into a phonegap project.

The prompts are really annoying during debug.  I got tired of always clicking cancel and I have resorted to installing a fake prompt function inside the javascript:

```
var require,
    define;
function prompt(asdf){return null;}//TODO DELETE THIS LINE BEFORE PRODUCTION
(function () {
```

This is obviously hacky and I'm looking for a more elegant solution.